# Dynamically populate Dropdown value and text using ajax json call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsp

I want to dynamically populate a dropdown list text and value using an ajax call to retrieve a JSONObject. 
My code populates the dropdown correctly but I want the value to be different from the text because I want to save the id in my database rather than the name.

This is my code:

```
            function get_landlords(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "get_landlord_list.jsp",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                var options, index, select, option;
                select = document.getElementById("landlord");


                select.options.length = 0;
                options = data.data;

                for(index = 0; index < options.length; ++index){
                    option = options[index];
                    if(option.company_name !== null){
                        select.options.add(new Option(option.landlord));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

<select name="landlord" id="landlord" class="form-control" onfocus="javascript:get_landlords();">
 <option value="-1" name="-" selected>-</option>
</select>
```

My json is as follow:

```
0: {landlord: "John Doe", id: 6}
1: {landlord: "John Doe", id: 4}
2: {landlord: "John Doe", id: 1}
3: {landlord: "John Doe", id: 3}
```

Anyone have a solution?

Comment: Maybe use a hidden input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the option value to a different value than the text for each option, you just need to specify that when you're creating the new option.

```
select.options.add(new Option(option.landlord, option.id));
```

You can look at this URL to get more info about adding a new option: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dd757810%28v=vs.85%29.aspx